# Redirect from a subdomain subfolder to a root subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My domain "*example.com*" is redirected (from cPanel) to the "*subdomain.example.com*". The "*subdomain.example.com*" is linked to a root subfolder "*example.com/blog*". So far so good.

Now I want to install Moodle in a proper root subfolder "*example.com/moodle*" and to link the subdomain URL "*subdomain.example.com/moodle*" to that subfolder, while keeping this URL in the address bar.

I tried in my "*subdomain.example.com/.htaccess*" file this, but without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/moodle
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/moodle/$1 [R=301]
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is DOCUMENT_ROOT of "subdomain.example.com" set to `"example.com/blog"` ?

Comment: I think yes. In cPanel, the DOCUMENT_ROOT of "subdomain.example.com" is set to _public_html/blog_.

Comment: Well in that case `"example.com/moodle"` is out of bounds for "subdomain.example.com". A domain cannot access files/directory above its DOCUMENT_ROOT level

Comment: Is there another solution? I want separate subfolders for my blog (/blog) and for Moodle (/moodle), but I want also the URL _subdomain.example.com/moodle_.

Comment: Well that is simple, You can have 2 subfolders under DOCUMENT_ROOT of `"subdomain.example.com"` 1: blog 2: moodle

Comment: OK, thank you! I must to rethink the site structure.